# Avoid multiple case when sub case

Tags: sql-server, case-when

I have this query where the 'sum("same")' is only here to avoid write the same condition as the first case

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (1,2,3) THEN sum(CASE WHEN @Amount = 'NETEXT' THEN NetExternalExcPcEuroBudget 
                                               WHEN @Amount = 'NETAGENCY' THEN NetAgencyIncPcEuroBudget
                                               ELSE NetAgencyIncPcEuroBudget + NetExternalExcPcEuroBudget
                                            END
                                         )END AS Q1,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (4,5,6) THEN sum("same")END AS Q2,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (7,8,9) THEN sum("same")END AS Q3,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (10,11,12) THEN sum("same")END AS Q4,
    monthId, 
    RefYearId AS Year
FROM [dbo].[FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard]
```

I would like to avoid the second CASE WHEN sub condition, I imagined I could use a join ? How to do so ? I would like to call only one time the Sub-Case When.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE to define, and then use it in your query :

```
;with amount as (
   select monthId, RefYearId AS Year, CASE WHEN @Amount = 'NETEXT' THEN NetExternalExcPcEuroBudget 
   WHEN @Amount = 'NETAGENCY' THEN NetAgencyIncPcEuroBudget
   ELSE NetAgencyIncPcEuroBudget + NetExternalExcPcEuroBudget
    END amount
from [dbo].[FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard]
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN MonthId in (1,2,3) THEN sum(amount.amount)END AS Q1,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (4,5,6) THEN sum(amount.amount)END AS Q2,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (7,8,9) THEN sum(amount.amount)END AS Q3,
    CASE WHEN MonthId in (10,11,12) THEN sum(amount.amount)END AS Q4,
    monthId, 
    RefYearId AS Year
FROM [dbo].[FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard]
        inner join amount on [FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard].monthId = amount.monthId and [FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard].RefYearId = amount.year
group by FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard.monthId, FactMonthlyConfirmationDashboard.RefYearId;
```